# How to show save as on Internet browser of a mobile device

Tags: javascript, android, html, mobile

I am writing a page (html, javascript) that is going to be used absolutely for mobile devices.
This page is going to serve some files (typeof: pdf, doc, docx and many others) that browser doesn't recognize. How can I force browser to give the option of saving file and open it with the appropriate installed app?
I tried _blank but nothing, it opens the page and ... raw data appear (not even a new tab starts).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you need to make sure the web server is serving the correct mime-type for your content. For uncommon or forced-download types, it can be served as `application/octet-stream`.